# Bind model to DropDownList using Razor syntax

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, api, razor

Okay, I have this view with the following Razor syntax:

```
@model DoggrOPI.Models.WellSearch

<div class="container-fluid">

    <h2>Well Search</h2>

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Counties.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Counties[i].CountyName)
    }

</div>
```

It displays:

```
Value 1Value 2Value 3
```

That is exactly what I want but I can't bind it to @Html.DropDownListFor. What is the proper syntax to do so?

My model is like this:

```
public partial class CountyInfo
{
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Whats the property you want to bind the selected value to?

Comment: Can you just give me an example and tell me which property. I just need anything Nothing works.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyProperty, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "CountryID", "CountryName")` will create options for each item in `Countries` where the value of the option is `CountryID` and the display text of the option is `CountryName`. The value of the selected option will be bound to property `MyProperty` when you post the form

Comment: Receive the following error: Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'DoggrOPI.Models.WellSearch' does not contain a definition for 'MyProperty' and no extension method 'MyProperty' accepting a first argument of type 'DoggrOPI.Models.WellSearch' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Comment: I gave you an example (you haven't posted your model for either `WellSearch` or `Countries`!). Just replace `MyProperty` with the name of a property in `WellSearch` that you want to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

Models:

```
public class WellSearch
{
     public int CountyId { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<CountyInfo> Counties { get; set; }
}

public partial class CountyInfo
{
    public int CountyId {get; set;}
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountyId , new SelectList(Model.Counties), "CountyId", "CountyName "))
```

Basically add a `CountyId` to your main view model and when you send your form to the server it will match your selected dropdown option.